# I cannot have 2 or multiple const on React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, constants, jsx

I'm relatively new in reactjs but I got these errors when I'm trying to include 2 const in one return - Modal from React-strap and the about content, I get errors I cannot figure out how to fix it.

I'm trying to create a simple website but will be using modal functions on every page, but I don't want to create separate files modal.js modal2.js modal3.js how to solve this issue or better another way to achieve this? thanks

see below and screenshot

thanks

```js
import React from "react";
import { Jumbotron as Jumbo, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

//here is where i added the ModalExample
export const About = () => { const } ModalExample = (props) =>  (

  const {
    buttonLabel,
    className
  } = props;

  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setModal(!modal);

  <React.Fragment>
    <Jumbo fluid className="jumbo">
      <div className="overlay"></div>
      <Container>
        <h1>About us</h1>
        <p>Learn to code </p>
      </Container>
    </Jumbo>

    <div>
      <Container>
        <h2>About Page</h2>
        <p>This is mostly about us page.</p>
        <p>
          Stare at ceiling lay on arms while you're using the keyboard so this
          human feeds me,
        </p>
      </Container>
    </div>
    <div>
      <Button color="danger" onClick={toggle}>{buttonLabel}</Button>
      <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} className={className}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>Cancel</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm note entirely sure what you are trying to implement exactly, but `const About = () => { const }` is a function that does not return anything. With this `ModalExample = (props) =>  (...)` you have an implicit return, but proceed with variable assignments via destructuring instead of returning JSX.

Comment: sending [screenshot of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) is source of many downvote, please move your code into a code block

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this:

```js
export const About = () => { const } ModalExample = (props) =>  (
```

I don't exactly know what you're trying to do, but you will either have to do this:

```js
export const About = () => {
  ...
```

or this:

```js
const ModalExample = (props) =>  (
```

You can't do both at the same time (you can make a function return a function, but I don't think that's a good idea with React components).

UPDATE:

Btw, if you want to make a function return a function you have to write it like this:

```
export const About = () => (props) => (
  ...
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, i was trying to achieve this.

I imported a modal button and content from Modal.js but i need to re-use them on different pages of the site.

anyways to achieve this?

I think i did not explain well and im new to stackflow on how it works.

thanks for your time.